# What is "Running AS3 attached to frame" and why is it killing my startup time?

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, air

I'm working on a desktop application in Adobe AIR, and I've been looking to decrease startup time. I used Adobe Scout and found that **Running AS3 attached to frame** takes a considerable amount of time (5058ms)

[image: Adobe Scout startup information for AIR application]

What is this exactly, and how can I slim this down? I moved all my constructor code into an *init* function, in hopes that would help, but the difference was infinitesimal. I have no timeline code. Bitmaps/movieclips are stored in the library.

Any help is appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This depends on what do you have in your startup script. It's possible that this script is really complicated and thus runs for a long time.

Comment: My startup script? I'm not running anything (that I know of) before the window is drawn. This all happens on the first frame. Can you elaborate?

Comment: That's the time it takes to run your code.  Click on it "Running AS3...".  The code will be shown in the "Actionscript" window (add it if you don't have it).

Comment: Perfect! Forgot to enable advanced telemetry, so that explains why I wasn't seeing anything. Appreciate the help, @moot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted above:

> Click on "Running AS3...". The code will be shown in the "Actionscript" window
>
> Also, enable advanced telemetry to troubleshhot the root cause of the slow startup time.